# show google map in react js

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I have installed react module via 'crate-react-app' command. Now I want to show the google map on my contact-us page. In page html, google map related js files loading at the end of file like below -

=====================================

```
    <!-- External JavaScripts
    ============================================= -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>

    <!-- Footer Scripts
    ============================================= -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDMxJ92oBkSnVNHFX3R8XhtYQPEgk1_IiI"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gmap.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#google-map').gMap({
            address: 'Melbourne, Australia',
            maptype: 'ROADMAP',
            zoom: 14,
            markers: [
                {
                    address: "Melbourne, Australia",
                    html: '<div style="width: 300px;"><h4 style="margin-bottom: 8px;">Hi, we\'re <span>Envato</span></h4><p class="nobottommargin">Our mission is to help people to <strong>earn</strong> and to <strong>learn</strong> online. We operate <strong>marketplaces</strong> where hundreds of thousands of people buy and sell digital goods every day, and a network of educational blogs where millions learn <strong>creative skills</strong>.</p></div>',
                    icon: {
                        image: "images/icons/map-icon-red.png",
                        iconsize: [32, 39],
                        iconanchor: [32,39]
                    }
                }
            ],
            doubleclickzoom: false,
            controls: {
                panControl: true,
                zoomControl: true,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                scaleControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                overviewMapControl: false
            }
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So, in my public/index.html, I write code like this  -

===================

```
<body class="stretched">
        <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix"></div>   

        <div id="gotoTop" class="icon-angle-up"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/functions.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in Contactus.js component -  I have imported  - 
`import $ from 'jquery';`

and in `componentDidMount()` function added `$('#google-map').gMap({` part 
but don't know how to load below file in contactus.js component -

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDMxJ92oBkSnVNHFX3R8XhtYQPEgk1_IiI"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gmap.js"></script>`

Please help me to sort out this .

Comment: Try specifying that script in the index.html itself

Comment: please dont use jquery in react, why do this man? :(
you can use at hand components

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri , specifying in 'index.html' is not working.

Comment: @AlirezaValizade , can you plz share the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Someone already created GMaps component for react, much easier using this one instead trying to integrate it by yourself.

https://github.com/MicheleBertoli/react-gmaps

Comment: any other way to do it ?